# error in my code, was not declared in this scope

Tags: c

I think it should work, what I try to do is capture a value and print it on screen, but I get the following error.

> C:\Users\luis\Documents\c++\estructura de datos\ejemplo_lista.cpp In
>   function 'void mostrar()':
>   80    13  C:\Users\luis\Documents\c++\estructura de
>   datos\ejemplo_lista.cpp   [Error] 'list' was not declared in this scope
>   80    20  C:\Users\luis\Documents\c++\estructura de
>   datos\ejemplo_lista.cpp   [Error] 'value' was not declared in this scope

------start MAIN---------------------------------

```
  int main(){

    menu();
    show();

     getch();
}
```

------end MAIN------------------------------------

```
//Function Menu
    void menu()
    {
            NODE = NULL; 
        int choice;
        int value;
        while(choice!= 2){
         printf("********** MENU **********\n");
         printf ("1. Login data \n");
         printf ("2. exit \n");
         printf("**************************\n");
         scanf ("%i",&choice);


                switch (choice){
                    case 1:
                         printf("Please enter a value \n");
                         scanf("%i",&value);
                         add (list, value);
                         break;
                    case 2:
                         break;
               }
              system("pause");
            }

    }
```

input function

```
void add (NODE &list,int value)
{

   NODE aux_list;
   aux_list =(data_structure*) malloc (sizeof (data_structure));
   aux_list->data = value;
   aux_list->next = list;
   list = aux_list;
}
void show()
{

    NODE other_list;
   add(list, value);
   other_list = list;
   / / Display the elements of the list
    while(other_list != NULL)
     {
         printf("%i \n",other_list->data);
          other_list = other_list->next;

     }

}
```

--------------------- edit --------------------------

`ready to solve it this way
void mostrar(NODO lista,int valor)
{
    lista=NULL;`

Comment: Some please translate this german or whatever language it is.

Comment: It's definitely not german, italian or spain I would guess :-)

Comment: In `void mostrar()` you're using the names `lista` and `valor`, but it seems they haven't been declared before. On the other hand, in `void ingresar`, these names refer to parameters, so they're known.

Comment: Where is NODO being declared ? Also, you should initialize "eleccion" in the declaration "int eleccion = 0;".

Comment: You seem to use local variables as if they were global (they're not).

Comment: @P0W Definitely not german! Portuguese or spanish probably.

Comment: The language used is Spanish, not German or Portuguese.

Comment: @Luisruiz i'm spanish too, but when I post in stackoverflow, I use english, **sourcecode names and comments included**

Comment: I translated the sourcecode, but I didn't modify anything, errors included

Comment: @Luisruiz no. There's Spaniard Spanish (Spain) and Latin American Spanish (Americas)

Comment: It is spanish. I think that the objects and data in the code can be in any language, not necessarily in English. The standard C (1999 or 2011) have taken in account this matter very seriously, in order to open C to every non-English language. We have to do the same. On the other hand, the "only write code in English" position is close to be a discriminatory attitude.

Comment: @Manu343726 might want to take a look at the most upvoted answer to [this question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/1483/do-people-in-non-english-speaking-countries-code-in-english) :)

Comment: @ColeJohnson Sorry, I try to adjust in the best way, I am new at this

Comment: @ColeJohnson I think there are two reasons to code in english: First **programming languages grammars are based on english**, so writting names in other languages, such as spanish, is too ugly and confusing. Second, **the programming comunity uses english as its first language**.

Comment: Nobody forbids coding in languages other than English. And it's not forbidden to answer questions with code that contains non-English names (also see [this meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow)). However, you help (more) readers better understand your code if you use English names.

Comment: Apart for the spanish, there is also the C / C++ language problem. **C does not have references** Did the OP mean C++ ?

Comment: @Luizruiz there's nothing to be sorry for. I thought the same way when I was a kid. I used to think Spainards spoke the _same_ Spanish as Mexicans and everyone else. The different between Spainards and Latin American Spanish is pretty much the same as the difference between American and British English.

Comment: @DyP we do have localized Stack Overflow sites for people who don't speak English natively.

Comment: @Manu343726 I agree that the comunity uses English in plain talk. But the code is not necessary to be written in English all the time. This particular question has, obviously, an easy issue on the C syntax, and the meaning of the variables is not important.

Comment: @Manu343726 the tag to remove (if any) was `c`, not `c++`

Comment: @gx_ and @wildplasser sincerelly, i haven't seen the reference before. On the other hand, what I have seen before and I'm seeing now is `malloc` and `printf` + `scanf` everywhere. **Thats C++?**

Answer (score 1):

As the error message tells you, in function `void mostrar()` you use variables `lista` and `valor` that are not defined in the scope of this function.

Comment: This information is in the error message in the question itself.

Comment: you mean I should declare `list` and  `value` within  } {} , () in void mostrar()

Answer (score 1):

In `mostrar()` you attempt to use a variable lista. But lists in not decleared in that scope. You need to pass it as a parameter, or declare this variable in the function to avoid this error.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to declare the type of variable lista, 
or perhaps to declare it as a parameter in the function mostrar().

```
 NODO lista; /* This one */

 void mostrar(NODO lista)      /* Or this one */
```

The object lista must be accesible inside the function mostrar().

(Update: The question has been changed to have English identifiers, so I will add the translated version below):

```
 NODE list; /* This one */

 void show(NODE list)      /* Or this one */
```

Comment: @DyP do not understand your solution. lista mostrar o lista valor?

Comment: @Luisruiz You have to choose the better solution to your program. You need to have a variable lista of type NODO inside your function mostrar() (that is now called show()). The solution depends on the logic of your program. If lista is supposed to hold a value coming from the main program, then you have to use the 2nd solution, where lista is a parameter of the function. But, if lista is a variable that will be discarded after mostrar() is finished, then lista is temporary and the 1st solution applies.